# Brew just stays and never returns

Tags: macos, homebrew

I installed `brew` and managed to get it installing things, in between not sure what I did wrong, but some `brew` commands just stopped working (`brew install`, `brew doctor`) the command would just stay in the terminal and not move forward.

I have uninstalled `brew` a couple of times and this isn't helping.

My guess is that it started to happen after I installed Xcode and the Xcode CLT

Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it thanks to @mistym on #machomebrew IRC channel.

You'll want to run `xcode-select -switch` and point it at your Xcode.app.

E.g.

```
xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app
```